# Concat two integers into an integer in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table calle info with two columns which are ids and location, and they are both of the int type. Both of them are not primary keys. However, combinations of them is unique. Now I want to form a new column which is the concatenation of two. For instance, if my id is 12345 and my location is 12, then the resulting integer should be 1234512. Is there any way to do this in mysql?

Comment: So the combos of `12345`/`12` and `123451`/`2` would yield the same value?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? The standard solution to this is to create a compound key on two columns, not do weird string concatenation.

Comment: *However, combinations of them is unique.* Define composite primary key. *Is there any way to do this in mysql?* Simply concatenate - MySQL will convert them to strings implicitly.

Comment: I can't see any good use for such a column. I think you might actually want a unique constraint over both columns.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what the comments above are describing:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  ids INT NOT NULL,
  location INT NOT NULL,
  -- other columns...
  UNIQUE KEY (ids, location)
);
```

This table rejects a row if the values in that pair of columns is already present in another row of the table. Basically, it acts as if you have a unique column containing the concatenation of the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as posted:

Just concatenate the fields. MySQL will cast them as appropriate.

For example:

```
UPDATE myTable SET newTextField = CONCAT(intField1, intField2);
```